FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
I got an Error after executing this line in PowerShell:
Start-Process -FilePath "MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Test.accdb" -ArgumentList 'initFile="C:\myFile.ini"'

The Error:
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand 

I tried to correct the ArgumentList. How can I fix this error?

Start-Process -FilePath 'MSACCESS.EXE' -ArgumentList 'C:\Test.accdb', 'initFile="C:\myFile.ini"' does that work? 'C:\Test.accdb' is misplaced in your code, should be part of the argument list.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are passing two different values into the -FilePath parameter. This seems wrong.
Without having more information as to what you're trying to do, I can only assume that your command should be written as
Start-Process -FilePath "MSACCESS.EXE" -ArgumentList 'C:\Test.accdb', 'initFile="C:\myFile.ini"'

This makes more sense because you pass the database and a configuration file as arguments to the MS Access call.

Error fixed. Thanks a lot.

No bother @Abi. If you're happy with the answer, please mark it as the accepted answer.
